# initialize global key with widget without attach it to screen

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to initialize global key with stateless or stateful widget but without attaching this widget to screen.

i tried this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:ui' as ui show ImageFilter, Gradient, Image;

void main() {
   runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return MyAppState();
  }

}
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  @override
  void initState()async {
    var image = await getMarkerIcon(context);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Material(
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}
Future<ui.Image> getMarkerIcon(BuildContext context) async {
  final key = new GlobalKey();
  MarkerText widget = MarkerText(
    key: key,
  );
  widget.build(context);

  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
  ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
  return image;

  return image;
}

class MarkerText extends StatelessWidget {
  MarkerText({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('example');
  }
}
```

after this, I get globalKey with null currentContext and null currentState. 
any idea to do this task? 
and any explanation when exactly globalkey initialize?
thanks in advance

update : 
after one day search I found this 2 solutions in this link:
[Build the widget off screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408315/build-the-widget-off-screen)

Comment: I don't understand where is it built, I think it's impossible to call build from outside of the widget.

Comment: why you can't use something like that:
   MarketText getMarkerIcon(BuildContext context) async {
      final key = new GlobalKey<MarkerText>();
      return MarkerText(
        key: key,
      );
    }

Comment: it's not work, maybe the widget initialize when you attached to the root widget in runApp function,

Comment: Can you provide compilable code please? I think i can help you

Comment: i edit the quastion u can now see the full code, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the code u have attached few mistakes such a multiple returns and unused variable *MarkerText*

I try to make working code from it and got something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:ui' as ui show ImageFilter, Gradient, Image;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  MarkerText _markerText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _markerText = MarkerText(key: GlobalKey());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(child: _markerText),
            RaisedButton(child: Text("Press me"), onPressed: () async => {
              print(await _markerText.getMarkerIcon(context)) // just to show that it return image
            },)
          ],
        )));
  }
}

class MarkerText extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey key;

  MarkerText({@required this.key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<ui.Image> getMarkerIcon(BuildContext context) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    return image;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepaintBoundary(child: Text('example'));
  }
}
```

If you need some help to adjust it your needs, please specify it in detail

Comment: thank you very much for this work, actually that you add _markerText to the screen, you make it as a child for the container, but what I need is to build this marker widget and use the globalkey without adding it to the screen, in other words i don't want to add markerText to the widget tree

Comment: I think that widget that wasn't in the tree doesn't have any context,
"A handle to the location of a widget in the widget tree." from the doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html

Comment: What is the main goal of the functionality?

Comment: If you need to add to your Widget some key (let's say GlobalKey) then you have to add it into Widget Tree. If you just don't want to paint widget, you could check Offstage widget. 

Why exactly do you need a key for your Widget?

Comment: the main goal is to build widget then convert it to an image, after that, I can use this image to make a marker on google map, why I do this? because google map doesn't accept marker as widgets,  it just permits you to provide marker icon as Bitmap.

Comment: i find way to do this without showing the widget on the screen,check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408315/build-the-widget-off-screen

Comment: Do you use offstage? Can you answer your own question, please? I want to see solution

Comment: any info please?

Comment: as mentioned update section above, I wasn't able to build widget outside screen tree, but I build in the screen tree without showed on the screen, and i convert this widget to a Bitmap image and put it on GoogleMap.sorry for late answer